# self join with max value

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am have a table with 500k transactions. I want to fetch the last balance for a particular date. So I have have returned a query like below.

```
    SELECT curr_balance
      FROM transaction_details
     WHERE acct_num = '10'
       AND is_deleted = 'N'
       AND ( value_date, srl_num ) IN(
            SELECT MAX( value_date ), MAX( srl_num )
              FROM transaction_details
             WHERE TO_DATE( value_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) 
                <= TO_DATE( ADD_MONTHS( '05-APR-2012', 1 ), 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
              AND acct_num = '10'
              AND is_deleted = 'N'
              AND ver_status = 'Y' )
       AND ver_status = 'Y'
```

This has to be executed for incrementing of 12 months to find the last balance for each particular month. But this query is having more cpu cost, 12 times it is taking huge time. How to remodify the above query to get the results in faster way. Whether this can be broken into two part in PL/SQL to achieve the performance. ?

Comment: What structure has the `transaction_details` table.Has it got a PK?

Comment: As it is a transaction table it doesnt contain PK. But there is a index created on acct_num,srl_num,value_date

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to query your table twice. Try using [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm)

```
SELECT t.curr_balance
    -- , any other column you want as long it is in the subselect.
FROM (
    SELECT
        trans.curr_balance
        , trans.value_date
        -- any other column you want
        , trans.srl_num
        , MAX(trans.srl_num) OVER(PARTITION BY trans.value_date, trans.srl_num) max_srl_num
        , MAX(trans.value_date) OVER(PARTITION BY trans.value_date, trans.srl_num) max_date
    FROM transaction_details trans
    WHERE TO_DATE( value_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) <= TO_DATE( ADD_MONTHS( '01-APR-2012', 1 ), 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
        AND acct_num = '10'
        AND is_deleted = 'N'
        AND ver_status = 'Y'
) t
WHERE t.max_date = t.value_date
    AND t.max_srl_num = t.srl_num
```

A couple of thoughts.

- Why do you have `TO_DATE( value_date...`? Isn't your data type `DATE`? this might be breaking your index if you have one in that column.
- Note that (this is a wild guess) if your `srl_num` is not the highest for the latest date, you will have incorrect results and might not return any rows.

Comment: Whether this would reduce the cost and increase the performance ?

Comment: @jollyboy You test it. See the query plan, I think the most critical part is that you break your index making that to_date conversion.

Comment: I have removed the to_date for value date as it is date datatype

Comment: @jollyboy And so? what the query plan said? did the performance change? did my answer help?

Comment: yes it got reduced to half...(but still to check the return value) ...also there is no index to value date and I have created and checking again....

Comment: @jollyboy So. You don't understand the query?. If you did, you could definitely work from the two answers you already have. What are your doubts exactly?

Comment: The curr_balance is for starting from 5th of a month to 5th of next month for n months.So the task is to get the curr_balance for srl_num and value_date equal to max(srl_num),max(value_date) from value date less than 05-MM-YYYY (lastest srl_num and last value date).

ex:

srl_num value_date curr_balance
------- ---------- ------------
1 01/02/2012 1000
2 04/02/2012 2000
3 04/02/2012 3000
4 10/02/2012 4000
5 15/02/2012 5000
6 30/02/2012 10000

The expected output is 3000. Also Query will be executed on 30 date or any date greated than 5th for a given month.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from(
    SELECT value_date, srl_num, curr_balance
      FROM transaction_details
     WHERE acct_num = '10'
       AND is_deleted = 'N'
       AND ver_status = 'Y'  
       row_number() over (partition by trunc(value_date - interval '5' day,'MM') 
                         order by srl_num desc
                         ) as rnk
       )
where rnk = 1;
```

You'll get a report with the ballance on last srl_num on each month in your table.

The benefit is that your approach scans the table 24 times for 12 months report and my approach scans the table once.

The analytic function gets the rank of record in current month(partition by clause) ordering the rows in the month after srl_num.

Comment: Sorry !!! i have updated the date us 5th of each month.So the above query wouldnt work...

Comment: Ah, I got it. It is simple to modify the partition clause to obtain what you want. I've modified it.

Comment: <= TO_DATE( ADD_MONTHS( '05-APR-2012', 1 ), 'dd/mm/yyyy' )